# win7: Move ALL windows to the main or a distinct display

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

### setup

i have several multi monitor setups where the main display changes but 
the current target setup is this:

- hp zbook 15 g2
- 2x acer hul WQHD with daisy chaining

### step 1/problem 1

after coming out of standby i must turn the daisy-chained display 1st off (if it was just on standby) and then on, otherwise the 2nd display isnt recognized.

PS: i guess that this is a driver/zbook problem and so i dont expect a solution for this problem but it would be a bonus ;) -- because i dont have this problem with the same setup on a GTX 960.

### problem 2

after having done this, the display config is correctly restored with the correct main monitor set; but: all my windows are still on the laptop display, which is now the 3rd display and least used.

### wanted

what i want is that all of the windows (i have like 20+ open being a super/poweruser/developer) are moved to the main display.

so anyone knows of a tool to move all of the windows to the main display ? 
if not i will script/program smth. myself.

### current workaround

i know of the win+shift+arrow shortcuts but i have to do this for all windows which is that i'm doing now but it is cumbersome!

### not working ideas

- disable the laptop display and then recactivating it
- toggle the primary display

Comment: I switch back to 'single monitor' then back to extended desktop. It's not very elegant and quite slow so I hope someone has a real solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same issue.

I found Display fusion resolved most of my triple display issues.

The script I use is with display fusion is below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

// The 'windowHandle' parameter will contain the window handle for the:
// - Active window when run by hotkey
// - Window Location target when run by a Window Location rule
// - TitleBar Button owner when run by a TitleBar Button
// - Jump List owner when run from a Taskbar Jump List
// - Currently focused window if none of these match

public static class DisplayFusionFunction
{
    public static void Run(IntPtr windowHandle)
    {
        // get visible window handles
        IntPtr[] handles = BFS.Window.GetVisibleWindowHandles();

        // loop through window handles and send each to the next monitor
        for (int i = 0; i < handles.Length; i++)
            BFS.Window.MoveToNextMonitor(handles[i]);
    }
}
```

https://www.displayfusion.com/

Comment: thx that tools seems to work. hint: they already have in-built functions now to move all windows to the current or main display and i bound those to keys